# #1932 table 'phpmyadmin.pma_tracking' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: phpmyadmin

My box is Scientific Linux 7.1 x64 and `xampp` 5.6.14-3 x64.

After installing `xampp`, I opened `phpmyadmin` and created databases and users, then I got this error message everytime:

```
#1932 table 'phpmyadmin.pma_tracking' doesn't exist in engine
```

Any comments would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I face the same issue and I follow the below step and resolve the issue. - In PHPMyAdmin fire direct Query in SQL. https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/sql/create_tables.sql - If you still face this issue, then delete mysql>data>phpmyadmin folder and after try to fire below URL Query in SQL. enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work with some changes in `/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`:

Add `$i=1` after `/* server parameters */`

---

```
/* Server parameters */

$i = 1
```

And fix the tablespaces of phpMyAdmin by following the [directions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11506495/2364405).

Comment: Thanks. It works great for me by replacing my config.inc.php with your content.

Answer (score 1):

just install an earlier version, I installed is
http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/5.6.12/

Comment: Indeed this seems to be a problem with a recent XAMPP release and the easy solution is to use an older version for now.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing and for several days looked for ways to fix it.

and somehow this happened, I seem to have fixed it by making a few changes to this code:
from -> $ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
to -> $ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

so my config.inc.php code will be like this:

```
<? php
/ *
* This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt passwords in
* cookie
* /
$ cfg ['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; / * YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! * /

/ *
* Servers configuration
* /
$ i = 0;

/ *
* First server
* /
$ i ++;

/ * Authentication type and info * /
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['user'] = 'root';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['password'] = '';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$ cfg ['Lang'] = '';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['compress'] = false;
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/ * Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp * /
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/ * User for advanced features * /
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['controluser'] = 'pma';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['controlpass'] = '';

/ * Advanced phpMyAdmin features * /
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['history'] = 'pma__history';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';

// $ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['users'] = 'pma__users';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';

/ *
* End of servers configuration
* /

?>
```

Comment: Nota bene: The `config.inc.php` file is located in xampp's `phpMyAdmin` folder.

Answer (score 0):

This works in XAMPP 5.6.3, php 7.3.9 just copy and paste this code in config.inc.php in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin and remember username is root and you do not have any password so password is empty.

```
<?php

/*

 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in

 * cookie

 */

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */



/*

 * Servers configuration

 */

$i = 0;



/*

 * First server

 */

$i++;



/* Authentication type and info */



$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

$cfg['Lang'] = '';



/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */



/* User for advanced features */

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';



/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */



/*

 * End of servers configuration

 */



?>



-- Database : `phpmyadmin`

--

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `phpmyadmin`

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

USE phpmyadmin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Privileges

--

-- (activate this statement if necessary)

-- GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, ALTER ON `phpmyadmin`.* TO

--    'pma'@localhost;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__bookmark`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__bookmark` (

  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,

  `dbase` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',

  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',

  `label` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',

  `query` text NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)

)

  COMMENT='Bookmarks'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__column_info`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__column_info` (

  `id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,

  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `column_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `comment` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',

  `mimetype` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',

  `transformation` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',

  `transformation_options` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',

  `input_transformation` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',

  `input_transformation_options` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',

  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),

  UNIQUE KEY `db_name` (`db_name`,`table_name`,`column_name`)

)

  COMMENT='Column information for phpMyAdmin'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__history`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__history` (

  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,

  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  `sqlquery` text NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),

  KEY `username` (`username`,`db`,`table`,`timevalue`)

)

  COMMENT='SQL history for phpMyAdmin'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__pdf_pages`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__pdf_pages` (

  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `page_nr` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,

  `page_descr` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',

  PRIMARY KEY  (`page_nr`),

  KEY `db_name` (`db_name`)

)

  COMMENT='PDF relation pages for phpMyAdmin'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__recent`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__recent` (

  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `tables` text NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)

)

  COMMENT='Recently accessed tables'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__favorite`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__favorite` (

  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `tables` text NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)

)

  COMMENT='Favorite tables'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__table_uiprefs`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__table_uiprefs` (

  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `prefs` text NOT NULL,

  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`db_name`,`table_name`)

)

  COMMENT='Tables'' UI preferences'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__relation`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__relation` (

  `master_db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `master_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `master_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `foreign_db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `foreign_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `foreign_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  PRIMARY KEY  (`master_db`,`master_table`,`master_field`),

  KEY `foreign_field` (`foreign_db`,`foreign_table`)

)

  COMMENT='Relation table'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__table_coords`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__table_coords` (

  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `pdf_page_number` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',

  `x` float unsigned NOT NULL default '0',

  `y` float unsigned NOT NULL default '0',

  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`pdf_page_number`)

)

  COMMENT='Table coordinates for phpMyAdmin PDF output'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__table_info`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__table_info` (

  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `display_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`)

)

  COMMENT='Table information for phpMyAdmin'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__tracking`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__tracking` (

  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `version` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,

  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,

  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,

  `schema_snapshot` text NOT NULL,

  `schema_sql` text,

  `data_sql` longtext,

  `tracking` set('UPDATE','REPLACE','INSERT','DELETE','TRUNCATE','CREATE DATABASE','ALTER DATABASE','DROP DATABASE','CREATE TABLE','ALTER TABLE','RENAME TABLE','DROP TABLE','CREATE INDEX','DROP INDEX','CREATE VIEW','ALTER VIEW','DROP VIEW') default NULL,

  `tracking_active` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',

  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`version`)

)

  COMMENT='Database changes tracking for phpMyAdmin'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__userconfig`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__userconfig` (

  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  `config_data` text NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (`username`)

)

  COMMENT='User preferences storage for phpMyAdmin'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__users`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__users` (

  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`usergroup`)

)

  COMMENT='Users and their assignments to user groups'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__usergroups`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__usergroups` (

  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `tab` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `allowed` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',

  PRIMARY KEY (`usergroup`,`tab`,`allowed`)

)

  COMMENT='User groups with configured menu items'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__navigationhiding`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__navigationhiding` (

  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `item_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `item_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`item_name`,`item_type`,`db_name`,`table_name`)

)

  COMMENT='Hidden items of navigation tree'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__savedsearches`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__savedsearches` (

  `id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,

  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `search_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',

  `search_data` text NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),

  UNIQUE KEY `u_savedsearches_username_dbname` (`username`,`db_name`,`search_name`)

)

  COMMENT='Saved searches'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__central_columns`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__central_columns` (

  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `col_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `col_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `col_length` text,

  `col_collation` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `col_isNull` boolean NOT NULL,

  `col_extra` varchar(255) default '',

  `col_default` text,

  PRIMARY KEY (`db_name`,`col_name`)

)

  COMMENT='Central list of columns'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__designer_settings`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__designer_settings` (

  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `settings_data` text NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)

)

  COMMENT='Settings related to Designer'

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;



-- --------------------------------------------------------



--

-- Table structure for table `pma__export_templates`

--



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma__export_templates` (

  `id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `export_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

  `template_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,

  `template_data` text NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  UNIQUE KEY `u_user_type_template` (`username`,`export_type`,`template_name`)

)

  COMMENT='Saved export templates'
http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/5.6.12/

  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```